# How to use regex quantifiers to rename multiple files with zmv?

Tags: command-line, shell, regex, zsh

I have the following files in a single directory:

```
1-1 - different text for each file here.txt
1-2 - different text for each file here.txt
.
.
1-9 - different text for each file here.txt
1-10 - different text for each file here.txt
1-11 - different text for each file here.txt
1-12 - different text for each file here.txt
.
.
```

I want to rename the files all at once (using `zmv` running in `zsh`) to:

```
1-01 - different text for each file here.txt
1-02 - different text for each file here.txt
.
.
1-09 - different text for each file here.txt
1-10 - different text for each file here.txt
1-11 - different text for each file here.txt
1-12 - different text for each file here.txt
```

Here's what I tried: `zmv '1-([0-9])(*)' '1-0$1$2'`

This results in following file names:

```
1-01 - different text for each file here.txt
1-02 - different text for each file here.txt
.
.
1-09 - different text for each file here.txt
1-010 - different text for each file here.txt
1-011 - different text for each file here.txt
1-012 - different text for each file here.txt
.
.
```

So I thought I'd change the find pattern to  `zmv '1-([0-9]{1})(*)' '1-0$1$2'` to match only files with a single digit after the hyphen, but this doesn't work
(I just get `zmv:232: no matches found: 1-([0-9]{1})(*)`).

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible using `zmv` or should I use something like `sed` in a `for` loop or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
zmv '1-([0-9])( *)' '1-0$1$2'
```

or

```
zmv '1-([0-9])([^0-9]*)' '1-0$1$2'
```

You just need to make the match include only one digit followed by a space or non-digit. With the way you had it, it was matching one digit followed by *anything*.

Comment: Argh, it was so simple, but I didn't see it! Thanks for opening my eyes. :)